# no module found even when installed in pipenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pipenv

I have the below notebook trying to use a module that I've installed from a Pipfile. I ran `pipenv install census` and then `pipenv shell` and then `jupyter notebook` and couldn't import.

I then tried `pipenv install` in the shell and then went back in the notebook still no module. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Try "pipenv run jupyter notebook"

Comment: @gajendragarg no dice

Comment: Try changing Kernel in Jupyter.